# Webpack plugin for Extracting Language bundles for each chunk

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-plugin

We have a custom setup for handling translations where at build time we extract the translations, download them and at runtime substitute them. Basically we extract the translation tags using a babel plugin and then once we have all the tags generate a file with them for each language.

Example

```
  <Trans
    tag="tag_name"
    variables={{
      var1,
      var2
    }}
  />
```

Generates list of tags like this

```
[
  {
    "tag": "tag_name"
  }
]
```

Then the values for the tags are fetched for each language. The translation values are currently javascript functions for each tag. Currently we generate 1 translation bundle for each language for the entire app.

This solution however is not scalable since this leads to a big translation bundle. Hence we want to split this by bundle/chunk.

To solve this we want to include the translation data in the chunk/bundle. We go over the code and extract the translation tags and figure out which tags belong to which chunk. For this we have built a plugin that hooks into the `optimizeTree` hook in the compilation.

After this we want to add them to the respective chunks and include them in the code.

For this we are facing a few issues:

- Is there a way to avoid the build process again for each language? Basically once the chunk/bundle is generated, can we just add the translation data to it?
  We want to generate one chunk for each language. So we have to copy some code in the chunk ‘n’ times  for each language. How can we do this in an optimized manner.
- How to make sure the imports to the files resolves to import the translated files?